How can I set debug Qt libraries to a custom target?
With cmake and C++, I have a configuration type called "ToolDebug" that I want to link the debug libraries too. As per usual Qt6 and cmake, I use
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui OpenGL)

However, this will only set the debug version of the libraries to Debug, and set the release versions to ToolDebug. How can I set the debug versions to ToolDebug? I tried to manually set them with the following, this will set the debug and the release versions
target_link_libraries(TableEditor 
    $<$<CONFIG:ToolDebug>:${Qt6_PREFIX_PATH}/lib/Qt6Cored.lib ${Qt6_PREFIX_PATH}/lib/Qt6Widgetsd.lib ${Qt6_PREFIX_PATH}/lib/Qt6Guid.lib>
)

For reference, I am using Qt6 and cmake 3.28.1

'I have a custom target called "ToolDebug"' - As you use expression $<CONFIG:ToolDebug>, it looks like ToolDebug is NOT a custom target, but a configuration type (which could be passed e.g. via --config option to cmake). Am I right? If yes, then please edit your post to use proper terminology. (In CMake a "custom target" is the target created with add_custom_target.)

@Tsyvarev That is correct, I updated my post to reflect that

"However, this will only set the debug version of the libraries to Debug, and set the release versions to ToolDebug. How can I set the debug versions to ToolDebug?" - I am not quite understand what you have and what do you want. If in your custom configuration type you want to link your application with debug version of libraries, then just set the variable CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_TOOLDEBUG to the value Debug. After that use regular linkage with QT: target_link_libraries(TableEditor QT6::Core).
